# Using custom identity database instead of ASP.NET core Identity

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Using custom identity database instead of ASP.NET core Identity and authenticating via cookie! (cookie auth works as expected however "User.Identity.Name" is always empty?)

How do I set and get the claim identity name "User.Identity.Name" ?

```
var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", "john"), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the same claim type you used inside your "name" claim to the constructor of `ClaimsIdentity`:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    claims,
    "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
    "name",
    ClaimTypes.Role);
```

If you do not specify claim types the default values are `ClaimTypes.Name` and `ClaimTypes.Role`, which you are seeing with your debugger as `NameClaimType` and `RoleClaimType` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your image the type name of the name claim is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/identity/claims/name`. This means you are using the ws federation claim types (which are the default).

You can either use that default type to set your name claim.

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "john");
```

Or you can overwrite the mapping in your `StartUp` which saves you from doing it in your authorization controller.

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
     // or `= "name"` if you dont want the dependency
     options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
}
```

The other two claim type names that come to mind and would make sense to overwrite are these two.

```
ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
```